# How to tell which properties have changed on an EF Core Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a project where I need to log the "columns" that have changed along with the original value and the changed value.  I have an EF Core Entity so I tried doing the following as a test:

```cs
var existing = _context.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 5);
existing.Lastname += " III";

var changes = new List<Tuple<string,object,object>>();
var proplist = typeof(Person).GetProperties();
foreach(var prop in proplist)
{
   var orig = _context.Entry(existing).OriginalValues[prop.Name];
   var curr = _context.Entry(existing).CurrentValues[prop.Name];
   if(orig != curr){
     changes.Add(new Tuple<string,object,object>(prop.Name,orig,curr));
   }
}
```

I expected to simply see "Lastname" show up in my changes.  However, I get some weird stuff like Birthdate (DateTime value), Id (int value), etc.  The weird part is that the orig value and curr value of these entries are exactly the same -- that is, my entry in the changes table looks like: `"Id",2,2`.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a more reliable way to find which properties of an Entity have changed?

Comment: Have you tried checking `context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` ?

Comment: I hope that `_context.Entity(existing)` is a typo for `_context.Entry(existing)` and is not a part of your original code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try this -

```cs
var changes = new List<Tuple<string, object, object>>();
var entry = _context.Entry(existing);
foreach (var item in entry.CurrentValues.Properties)
{
    var propEnrty = entry.Property(item.Name);
    if (propEnrty.IsModified)
    {
        changes.Add(new Tuple<string, object, object>(item.Name, propEnrty.OriginalValue, propEnrty.CurrentValue));
    }
}
```

**Edit :**
I just ran your code, and found no problem with it. Following is what I got in the `changes` list  -

```cs
{(LastName, Cooper, Cooper III)}
```

But of course I used `_context.Entry(existing)` hoping that `_context.Entity(existing)` was a typo while posting and is not really a part of your original code.